# Divide results in two columns depending on the input values? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, northwind

I am using the Nortwind database with SQL Server 2014, I try to make a query to divide the results of the orders in two different years, The format that I want in my query is

```
category |anio one | anio two
```

where the years may vary , What I try so far is

```
SELECT ca.CategoryName , YEAR(o.OrderDate), SUM(ot.UnitPrice*ot.Quantity) as total
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ot ON O.OrderID = ot.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products pro ON ot.ProductID = pro.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ca ON pro.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
GROUP BY ca.CategoryName,YEAR(o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY ca.CategoryName;
```

This gives me the totals of each category for a different year, `1996-1997-1998` in column  `YEAR(o.OrderDate)`

[image]

I want to get for example

```
CategoryName | 1996 | 1997

Beverages   |53879,20 | 110424,00
Condiments  |19458,30 | 59679,00
....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "conditional aggregates".

```
SELECT
      ca.CategoryName
    , SUM(case when year(o.OrderDate) = 1996 then ot.UnitPrice * ot.Quantity end) AS total_1996
    , SUM(case when year(o.OrderDate) = 1997 then ot.UnitPrice * ot.Quantity end) AS total_1997
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ot ON o.OrderID = ot.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products pro ON ot.ProductID = pro.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ca ON pro.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
where o.OrderDate >= '19960101' and o.OrderDate < '19980101'
GROUP BY
      ca.CategoryName
ORDER BY
      ca.CategoryName
```

Basically that means use a case expression inside the aggregate function.

I case you are wondering why I have not used "between in the where clause: see
[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: it worked perfect. If I want to add more dates as parameters, I would have to add in the select another case and in the where truth? and ¿why not use year in the where ?

Comment: If you wanted to add more columns then you can either add more cases or use [dynamic sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql).

Comment: @DarkFenix yes you can keep adding new aggregation columns as needed. Dont forget to adjust the where clause to match as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. regards

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use PIVOT to get your desired Output

BEGIN TRAN
CREATE TABLE #Temp(CategoryName NVARCHAR(50),[Year]INT,TOTAL DECIMAL(15,2))

INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT ca.CategoryName , YEAR(o.OrderDate), SUM(ot.UnitPrice*ot.Quantity) as total
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ot ON O.OrderID = ot.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products pro ON ot.ProductID = pro.ProductID
INNER JOIN Categories ca ON pro.CategoryID = ca.CategoryID
GROUP BY ca.CategoryName,YEAR(o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY ca.CategoryName;


SELECT * FROM #Temp
GO
select *
from 
(
  select CategoryName, [Year], TOTAL
  from #Temp
) src
pivot
(
  sum(TOTAL)
  for YEAR in ([1996], [1997]
)) piv;

ROLLBACK TRAN
```

Comment: I like the solution and it works but I accepted the answer where it is not used pivot since I still do not understand this very well. Greetings and many thanks

Comment: @DarkFenix Pivot query help us to generate an interactive table that quickly combines and compares large amounts of data. We can rotate its rows and columns to see different summaries of the source data, and we can display the details for areas of interest at a glance. It also help us to generate Multidimensional reporting.

Answer (score 2):

you can use pivot to get the desired output

```
 CREATE TABLE #TEMP
 (
    Category VARCHAR(200),
    YEAR1 NUMERIC,
    Total MONEY
 )

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'beverages', 1996, 500
union
SELECT 'beverages', 1997, 750
union
SELECT 'Condiments', 1997, 1000
union
SELECT 'Condiments', 1996, 800


SELECT *
FROM
    (
      SELECT Category,YEAR1, Total  FROM #TEMP
    ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
   (
      AVG(Total) FOR YEAR1 IN ( [1996], [1997]) 
   ) AS PivotTable;
```